# Неправильный порядок городов в state, из за разного времени получения response с сервера(REDUX)

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, асинхронность

Суть в том что в localStorage хранится список городов. Я перебираю localStorage и для каждого ключа делаю запрос на сервер, а затем сетаю нужную информацию о каждом городе в state, затем из state список выводится с помощью map. Проблема в том, что из за разного времени получения ответов с сервера, список выводится не в том порядке, в котором они хранятся в localStorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо только отображать в правильном порядке или хранить тоже? В случае, если нужно только правильно отображать, предлагаю использовать Array.prototype.sort()

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!)